# Gray out 'out of stock' variables in woocommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a store with variable products that contains variables such as size, color and fabric. 
I use swatches for this and not dropdown

[image]

I've searched for answers but none of them worked for me. The only one that did, is still missing something.

I used this code in my functions.php file of my child theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );

function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ) {

if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() )
    return false;

return true;
}
```

and it's partially working. The swatches are not clickable, but the color of the text stays the same.
I've tried changing the swatches plugin 'out of stock products' setting like this:
[image]

but it did not work. I also tried looking at the source HTML code and found that the `<option>` is set to disabled but the `<ul>` isn't:
[image]

I know css, but the css I write does not work. I guess because the list itself is not showing the disabled attribute in it's tag. 
Is there a better code/way to do that? maybe something I'm missing?

you can see an example here: https://misfit.co.il/shop/t-shirts/badass-sleeveless-shirt/ BUT MAKE SURE YOU SEE IT IN MOBILE MODE CAUSE IT'S NOT YET DESIGNED FOR DESKTOP VIEW.

thanks.